# SELECT queries return results in unique key order

Tags: mysql

I ran into an interesting behavior/problem today.
Every time I start a query on my table I get results sorted by my unique key instead of my primary key.

My table columns:

```
id (PRIMARY KEY),  
name (UNIQUE KEY)
```

However, if I add another normal column it starts to behave normal again. 
 
Can someone explain this and/or give me a hint how to turn that off?

Comment: Um, use `ORDER BY` in your query?

Comment: If you don't specify an order, the order will depend on the used indexes. You shouldn't rely on the default result ordering.

Comment: @dystroy Why does the order get back to normal if I add a third (e. g. VARCHAR) column without any indexes?

Comment: @ArchSonix It's implementation dependent. Never do unordered queries if you need an ordered result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not seem to have documentation on this per se, but I did find this: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,239471,239688#msg-239688

Essentially, of you don't specify an `ORDER BY`, you should not trust the data to be returned in any particular order.  The default sort behavior also varies per engine.

Don't depend on order without `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no gurantee that in which order MySQL returns the row. It depends on MySQL Version, Storage Engine, Storage Engine version. Please see below link for more details

[Default Order of Records in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql)